# using less than or equal to symbol

Tags: equations

So this is my first LaTeX document. I am trying to write an in equality in this document. Given below is the code I have written

```
\documentclass[20pt]{article}

\usepackage{extsizes}

\begin{document}

Let f(x) be a real valued function of real variable such that  $ |f^n(0)|  \leq  K $

\end{document}
```

[image]
The code compiles without any error but where I should be getting a less than or equal to sign I instead get the letters leq. I have also tried using the code \le
. I also tried using the `\usepackage{amsmath}` command. But that generates an error undefined control sequence. Can somebody please correct this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you check  whether there's a space between the backslash and `leq` (something like this `\ leq`).?

Comment: @Bernard No there isn't. I tried putting the space and removing it. No difference

Comment: The package is extsize`s`, with an s.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is because the code is supposed to be \usepackage{extsizes} not \usepackage{extsize}. sorry for the mistake I will try to correct it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle even with the correct package I am getting "leq" instead of the symbol

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do you share the link to the output

Comment: You can show upload the image in your question. As a new user it will make a link rather than an inline image but we can change that. Also in an answer post below I have posted the full log file thet I get when I run your example. Can you add your log to your question to compare

Comment: the output you show really isn't possible:-) If you did not have any output character at all you that would be a missing font (and a warning would appear in the log) but `\leq` simply can not make `leq`  unless something is very wrong with your installation. Can you add `\show\leq` to your document and show what log you get?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know how but I got the less than or equal to sign now and I didn't even use \show. I just retyped the entire sentence and it worked!!!Whatever it might have been thank you

Comment: @SiddharthPrakash my guess would be that you had something between `\ `and `leq` maybe an invisible control character, although the version posted to this site was OK.

Comment: I suggest that you delete as there isn't really an answer that can be posted

Comment: For absolute value, use \lvert ... \rvert, for the vertical bar operator \mid (better spacing). I always use \le, \ge for comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this MWE will satisfy your request. Here there is a screenshot. You should also add the package for the symbols called `amssymb` to obtain `\leq` or 
    `\leqslant` symbol.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[20pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{extsizes}
    \begin{document}
    Let $f(x)$ be a real valued function of real variable such that

    \[ |f^n(0)| \leq K\]
    or \[ |f^n(0)| \leqslant K\] 

    \end{document}
```

Comment: why have you used `\preceq` not `\leq` when the question asks for less than or equal?

Comment: Because I have not understood the exact symbol that the user have searching. Now edit my code.

Comment: This still does not answer the question asked. which is why the code shown in the question does not produce a less than. You asked on meta about being asked for a MWE, there is a MWE here but you have ignored it.

Comment: @Sebastiano Copied your entire code and compiled. It shows the error " ! Undefined control sequence.
\set@mathaccent ...2}\hexnumber@ #1#4}\MakeRobust 
                                                  #2
l.770 \@tempa{\hat}". Do you understand what it means?

Comment: @SiddharthPrakash Do you compile with TeXlive, or Overleaf or other? It will probably be something about your outdated TeX distribution.